# How to restore casper-rw file to a casper-rw partition

Tags: linux, linux-mint, partition, live-usb, persistence

New to Linux and using Mint 17.2.
Started with persistent Live USB that ran out of space after a week.
So made a backup of everything (entire filesystem) including the **casper-rw file**, created new Live USB with **casper-rw partition** instead of file.
This currently works.

Now I want all the stuff back I had from that week of work. I want my programing includes and libraries, my themes, backgrounds... everything.

How do I do this?
And how should I have done this if I was still in the position of just running low on space?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you don't need the answer anymore (seeing its from '15), but here's what works:

- mount the `casper-rw` file on loopback, like so:

  ```
  mount /path/to/casper-rw /mnt/src/
  ```
- mount the partition you'd want to copy over the files to (ensure it is empty), like so:

  ```
  mount /dev/sdXN /mnt/tgt/
  ```

  where `sdXN` denotes the `N`th partition of `/dev/sdX`
- issue `rsync` in archival mode so that `symlinks`, modification-times are preserved

  ```
  rsync -avP /mnt/src/* /mnt/tgt
  ```

Wait for the command to finish and you are done.